# getting error "glassfish4/glassfish/lib/nadmin: 54: exec: java: not found" on running remote commands from DAS

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1, asadmin

when pinging a node from glassfish 4.1.2 DAS server using command "asadmin ping-node-ssh --validate=true ", returns:-

```
Successfully made SSH connection to node <mynode02> (node02.cloud.com)
GlassFish version found at /usr/local/server/glassfish4:
unknown version: /usr/local/server/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/nadmin: 54: exec: java: not found

Command ping-node-ssh executed successfully.
```

Even though, there is another instance running on different node working completely fine.
Similar "54: exec: java: not found" error i get when i try to start the instance on that node from DAS but locally i am able to start the instance.

Even though i have checked Java, it is there. Have also tried setting AS_JAVA value.

Answer (score 0):

DAS connects over SSH in batch mode, which in practice means that the environment configuration might be different when you log into the machine via terminal. Make sure that java command is in a standard path, e.g. /usr/bin/java. If not, create a symbolic link.